# Google Apps Script - autoResizeColumn error [out of bounds]

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that copies a sheet to another sheet and formats it. I'm just trying to get the columns to resize but I'm getting `Those columns are out of bounds` error.

```
function print_weekly_schedule(){

  // ************************
  // Sheet Variables Setup 
  // ************************
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var print = ss.getSheetByName("Print")
  var schedule = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule")

  // Create Weekly, Printable Schedule
  print.clear({formatOnly:true});
  print.deleteColumns(2, print.getMaxColumns()-1);
  print.deleteRows(2, print.getMaxRows()-1);

  print.insertRows(1, 1);

  schedule.getRange(8, 1, schedule.getMaxRows(), schedule.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(print.getRange(2, 1));  

  for (var i=1; i < print.getLastColumn(); i++){
    print.autoResizeColumn(i);
  }

}
```

A very similar script works in another function but I'm stumped why this isn't working. I've tried to `Logger.log(print.getLastColumn)` and I get back the desired number, 23.

When I debug this script, it stops on `i=2`

What am I missing here?

Comment: On what line is the error triggered from? Are you sure it's from `autoResizeColumn`? I tend to believe it comes from the `copyTo` line

Comment: I didn't want to answer my own question since it doesn't contribute. @Adelin is right, the issue was caused from `copyTo`. I had to create the rows first, then copy, then `autoResizeColumn`. Everything worked afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was down-voted, I wanted to explain.

`schedule.getRange (8, 1, schedule.getMaxRows(), schedule.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(print.getRange(2, 1));`

Works well, it will copy appropriately, but you won't be able to use `print.autoResizeColumn`. The only way to resize your columns is if you insert empty columns first, then copy over data and resize.

Full Implementation:

```
function print_weekly_schedule(){

  // ************************
  // Sheet Variables Setup 
  // ************************
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var print = ss.getSheetByName("Print");
  var schedule = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule");

  // Clear out content that is present
  print.clear({formatOnly:true});
  print.deleteColumns(2, print.getMaxColumns()-1);
  print.deleteRows(2, print.getMaxRows()-1);

  // Insert new row and columns
  print.insertRows(1, 1);
  print.insertColumns(1, 22);

  // Copy over content from previous tab  
  schedule.getRange(8, 1, schedule.getMaxRows(), schedule.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(print.getRange(1, 1), {contentOnly:true});  

  // Resize Columns
  for (var i=1; i < print.getLastColumn(); i++){
    print.autoResizeColumn(i);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps someone.